# can't find package udp while executing "package require udp"

Tags: tcl

I did '`# zypper search tcludp`' and got the below o/p

```
Loading repository data...
Warning: Repository 'openSUSE-13.2-Update' appears to be outdated. Consider using a different mirror or server.
Reading installed packages...

S | Name   | Summary                      | Type
--+--------+------------------------------+--------
  | tcludp | UDP Socket Extension for Tcl | package
```

but then too it couldn't able to find udp.Please explain what would be the issue and how can it be solved

Os : openSUSE 13.2 (Harlequin)
tcl : tcl_8.4.14

Comment: Tcl 8.4.14? That's [a minor version from 2006](http://wiki.tcl.tk/405#pagetocce1b0491)! Upgrade, even just to 8.4.20 if you can't make the jump to a supported version…

Comment: What does "but then too" mean? Do you mean you have actually installed the `tcludp` package using whatever tool your OS provides for this?

Comment: Ah, I see, it's listed as installed.  OK, the next step is to get the list of the files installed by that package using a suitable call to your package management tool (`zypper`?) and correlating it with the Tcl's idea of the places it looks for packages--run `set auto_path` in a Tcl shell.

Comment: BTW, expanding on what @DonalFellows said, [this](https://software.opensuse.org/package/tcl) lists 8.6.x as available for 13.2.

Comment: Got the solution.The o/p of  '# zypper search tcludp' is from opensuse and it doesn't mean that tcludp is installed in the server. so through yast i checked and found 'tcludp' is not installed, after installing the 'tcludp'. It works fine.Thanks for the help :)